# remove https from obiee which has Oracle traffic director

Tags: http, load-balancing, obiee

I have OBIEE with https. I need to remove it and make it http. Can anyone share reference to doing that. This OBIEE is load balanced by Oracle traffic director. Do I need to make any changes in traffic director.

I'm totally unaware of OTD.

Thank you in advance,
Shiva

Comment: You want to remove https? Why? Someone went through the trouble of setting it up and making things secure and you want to remove it??

Comment: I felt the same thing, why would anyone set it up in the first place if they want to remove it.My boss asked me this question, so I wanted to know whether it needs to be removed from OTD as well or not.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from my comment above - you basically have to undo the configuration done according to the documentation:

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21043_01/bi.1111/e10543/ssl.htm